# Eager load on polymorphic child object property

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

```
public class Parent 
{
  public ICollection<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{      
}

public class Boy : Child
{  
  public Toy Toy {get;set;}    
}

public class Girl : Child
{      
  public Book Book {get;set;}
}
```

I want to load all parents and eager load all children for each parent and for each Boy load the toy and for each Girl load the book.

How do I write that using Linq Include()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4.3.1 Include inherited navigation properties in LinqToEntities query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705218/ef-4-3-1-include-inherited-navigation-properties-in-linqtoentities-query)

Comment: @GertArnold, this is not a duplicate. `Children` is a polymorphic collection, not an inherited navigation property. Ian, have you found a solution to this? I'm looking too.

Comment: @kit Last time I looked the eager loading seems to be improving. I'm not sure if it fixes this. :)

Comment: Is this easily solvable now with EF6?

Comment: Sorry, things haven't changed essentially in this area.

Answer (score 5):

Can't be done with `Include` but can be done via projection - EF will wire up navigation properties for you as long as you select those entities (change tracking must be enabled):

```
var query = db.Parents.Select( p => new
{
    Parent = p,
    // get the children entities for the parent
    Children = p.Children,
    // get the toys for the parent's boys
    Toys = p.Children.OfType<Boy>().Select( b => b.Toy ),
    // get the books for the parent's girls
    Books = p.Children.OfType<Girl>().Select( g => g.Book ),
} );

var results = query.ToArray().Select( at => at.Parent );
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. Is there a way to do it that doesn't require the `ToArray()` so I can use it in a chain-able method on an `IQueryable<>`?

Comment: Sure, you just can't project to `at.Parent` only until after you enumerate the query